# A question about ring theory

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

> Consider the ring $R=\bigg\{\frac{2^km}{n} \ \bigg| \ m,n \ \text{odd integers; k is a non-negative integer}\bigg\}$.
>
> $(a)$ Describe all the units (invertible elements) of $R$.
>
> $(b)$ Exhibit one nonzero proper ideal $I$ of $R$.
>
> $(c)$ Examine whether the ideal $I$ you have chosen is a prime ideal of $R$.

Since $2^k$ is always a power of $2$, it is mutually prime with every odd $m,n$. Again if $b\in R$ is a unit of $R$, then there exists nonzero $a\in R$ such that $ab=ba=1$. So how to "describe" exactly the units of $R$ here? Again using the definition of an ideal of a ring, left or right multiplying any element of $I$ with that of $R$ takes it into $I$. So how to show this is prime?

Comment: $R$ consists of rationals with odd denominator. Which rationals $x$ have odd denominator and also have $1/x$ with odd denominator? If you are looking for ideals, remember that principal ideals are the easiest ones to work with.

Comment: Note that the condition on $k$ is that it is non-negative.  Nowhere does it say that $k$ must be *positive*.

Comment: If $x\in R$ and it has odd denominator then $1/x$ should have even denominator? Because it is a factor of $2^k$.

Comment: You're missing that $k$ can equal $0$.  As an example, both $5/3$ and $3/5$ are in $R$.  So is $10/3$, but $3/10$ isn't in $R$.

Answer (score 4):

Since you need odd denominators, you will never cancel a positive power of $2$. So the only option is $k=0$: the invertible elements are precisely
$$
L=\left\{\frac mn:\ m,n\ \text{ odd }\right\}.
$$

A nonzero ideal will consist of non-invertible elements. So this suggests fixing $k$ and taking $$I_k=\left\{\frac{2^hm}n:\ h\geq k, m,n\ \text{ odd }\right\}.$$ To check whether this is prime, if $ab\in I_k$, we have $a=2^hm/n$, $b=2^r s/t$, and 
$$
ab=\frac{2^{h+j}ms}{nt}.
$$ 
We see that we may obtain $k$ as the sum of two numbers strictly less than it.

In conclusion: $I_1$ is prime, but $I_k$, for $k\geq2$, is not. Because $2^k=2^{k-1}\times 2\in I_k$, while neither $2^{k-1}$ nor $2$ are in $I_k$.